# Is there a method to eliminate the jagged effect produced by the SVG feColorMatrix filter?

Tags: svg

There is a jagged effect around the Polygon after applying a `feColorMatrix` filter. I attempted to use `shape-rendering="geometricPrecision"` to eliminate this effect, but it was not successful. I would like to know if there is a way to make the border of the Polygon smooth after applying a feColorMatrix filter. Thanks for any help!

Here is my codepen: https://codepen.io/cactusxx/pen/mdvGRva

Code here:

```html
<svg style="width: 1200px; height:800px;">
  <defs>
<polygon id="polygon" points="300,30 380,60 300,90" shape-rendering="geometricPrecision" />
<filter id="polygonFilter" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
  <feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 
                                                        0 0 0 0 0 
                                                        0 0 0 0 0 
                                                        0 0 0 200 0">
</filter>
  </defs>
  <g filter="url(#polygonFilter)" style="overflow: hidden">
<use href="#polygon" stroke-width="5" stroke="rgb(255,100,100)" fill="rgb(255,0,0)" stroke-opacity="0.8" fill-opacity="0.5" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: The large value in the matrix eliminates antialiasing (as well as making the whole thing completely black), that causes it to look jagged. You could of course simply draw a black polygon and not filter it at all.

Comment: @RobertLongson Yep, you are right! I will try it.